# Multiply two lists of different length in R

Tags: r, list, dictionary, apply

I have two lists with different structures. List A is a list of dataframes (containing 1 row and 10 columns) and List B is a list of matrix 10x 10, like this:

```
List A

[[1]]
[1] dataframe (of 1 column)
[[2]]
[1] dataframe (of 1 column)

List B
[[1]]
[1] num (1:10)
[[2]]
[2] num (10 x 10)

Example:
ListA <- list(A = A <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10), ncol = 10, nrow = 1)),
              B = B  <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10), ncol = 10, nrow = 1)))

ListB <- list(B = A <- rnorm(10),
              A = B  <- rnorm(10)
              C = C <- rnorm(10) )
```

I would like to multiply (`%*%`) each data frame of lits A for each vector of list B.
Like this: `A%*%B, A%*%A, A%*%C, B%*%B, B%*%A, B%*%C` and also have the results with the names of each element calculated.

I tried `Map(%*%, ListA, ListB)` but is not working.

Comment: Also, Is there (or is it better) way to run this operation using the names of the element as the Lists are of different lengths? Example: `ListA$A %*% ListB$B`, `ListA$A %*% ListB$A`, `ListA$A %*% ListB$C`, `ListA$B %*% ListB$B`, `ListA$B %*% ListB$A`, `ListA$B %*% ListB$C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can try `outer` like below

```
outer(ListA,ListB,FUN = Vectorize(function(x,y) as.matrix(x)%*%y))
```

which gives results looking like

```
          B         A          C
A -1.336335 -1.291103  0.0925648
B -3.270517  4.648139 -3.8720215
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an `lapply` solution:

```
lapply(1:length(ListA), function(x) lapply(1:length(ListB), 
                                    function(y) as.matrix(ListA[[x]]) %*%  ListB[[y]]))

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
          [,1]
[1,] -4.061742

[[1]][[2]]
          [,1]
[1,] -1.401807

[[1]][[3]]
         [,1]
[1,] -1.53459


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
         [,1]
[1,] 3.439579

[[2]][[2]]
        [,1]
[1,] 2.44288

[[2]][[3]]
         [,1]
[1,] 3.475746
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `a lapply` ;)

Comment: thanks @BenNorris , but looking at the results, I didn't understand which operation returned each one of the results. Is there a way to include names to make each operation more evident

Comment: what is your suggestion, @Duck?

Comment: @BMT I meant the typo.

Comment: @Ben your suggestion didn't work it, unfortunately. My two lists a much bigger and I can't see all the results.

Answer (score 0):

We could also do this by looping over the object

```
lapply(ListA, function(x) lapply(ListB, function(y) as.matrix(x) %*% y))
```

Comment: thanks. What I need is a vector result with the correlation `(%*%)` of each element of List A (the column of each data frame) with each element (represent as a numeric vector) represented as numeric at List B.